# Can I set a status message to be displayed when a user clicks a link?

Tags: 8, navigation, status-messages

Here's my setup:

I have a page about Pineapples.  There is a link to the Pineapples page in the main navigation menu. When a user clicks that link, they go to the page.

I also have a separate link on the homepage to the Pineapples page.  When a user clicks the homepage link, I want to send them to the Pineapples page, but I also want to show a status message with a little more information.

Is there a Drupal-y way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make a custom form with a submit button (the button should be your "link" button), and then you can do what you want.